# What changed wwith Python in WDL change from draft 2 to version 1?

Tags: python, wdl

I'm updating my WDL from draft 2 (whichs works fine) to version 1. I'm stuck with a Py snippet

```
task getReadGroup {

    input {
        String inputFile
    }

    command {echo input = ${inputFile}}

    # command <<<
    # python <<CODE
    # print ("${inputFile}".strip().split('/'))
    # CODE
    # >>>

    output {
    Array[String] o = read_lines(stdout())
    }
}
```

This command gives the expected result:

```
input = /mnt/lustre/working/genomeinfo/data/20191015_LongRead/20191015_LongRead_1/data/LXBAB201271/LXBAB201271/LXBAB201271/20190417_0612_1-A7-D7_PAD44174_42dcde1a/fast5/test/
```

But the commented out python code:

```
print ("${inputFile}".strip().split('/'))
```

Gives an empty list - "${inputFile}" is empty in the code command for some reason!

Any ideas? I've tried using a File instead of String to make it just like the example in the docs (below) other than that I see no diff:

```
task heredoc {
  input {
    File in
  }

  command<<<
  python <<CODE
    with open("${in}") as fp:
      for line in fp:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
          print(line.strip())
  CODE
  >>>
}
```

Comment: print (inputFile.strip().split('/')). ??

Comment: Is that a wild guess or do you know?

Comment: Don’t know what is WDL and how it works but it’s like the variable it’s inputFile , and $ goes with echo, but could be wrong. Can’t try by my own given I don’t know WDL

Comment: Given u don't know what WDL is it would be best if you didn't make suggestions...

Comment: Fine https://github.com/openwdl/wdl/blob/main/versions/1.0/SPEC.md#command-section got the use of placeholders    in whatever WDL is

Comment: What does print ("${inputFile}") alone gives you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complements of Phil Shapiro;

Use ~{} instead of ${}.

So this example from the current docs is wrong:

```
task heredoc {
  input {
    File in
  }

  command<<<
  python <<CODE
    with open("${in}") as fp:
      for line in fp:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
          print(line.strip())
  CODE
  >>>
}
```

It should be :

```
task heredoc {
  input {
    File in
  }

  command<<<
  python <<CODE
    with open("~{in}") as fp:
      for line in fp:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
          print(line.strip())
  CODE
  >>>
}
```